# jQuery first of type selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I select the first `<p>` element in the following `<div>` with jQuery?

```
<div>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>How do I select this element with jQuery?</p>
    <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference to the `div` already:

```
$(yourDiv).find("p").eq(0);
```

If the first `p` will always be a direct child of the `div`, you could use `children` instead of `find`.

Some alternatives include:

```
$(yourDiv).find("p:eq(0)"); //Slower than the `.eq` method
$(yourDiv).find("p:first"); 
$(yourDiv).find("p").first() //Just an alias for `.eq(0)`
```

Note that the `eq` method will always be the fastest way to do this. Here's the results of a [quick comparison](http://jsperf.com/jq-first-vs-eq) of the `eq` method, `:eq` selector and `:first` selector (I didn't bother with the `first` method since it's just an alias of `eq(0)`):

[image]

Comment: Nice, this looks convincing, Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) If you're interested, yet another alternative would be `:lt(1)`. I'm almost certain it will be slower that the `.eq` method too, but it's yet another way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Wow, that is a significant difference.  I don't understand why jQuery would allow :first at all.  In the background, it should be converted to :nth-child(1). http://jsperf.com/jq-first-vs-eq/3  Is there a reason this isn't done?

Comment: @rkw - `:nth-child` does something very different. It returns the element at the specified index (1-based, just for added confusion!) *if it matches the selector*. In your jsperf test, the `:nth-child` example will not match any elements - the first element is an `h2`, not a `p`. I believe that behind the scenes, `:first` is converted to `:eq(0)`, which is shown in my original test.

Comment: @James, ah; thanks.  Now I know why people keep on asking about nth-of-type selectors for jquery.

Comment: @rkw - Yeah, the naming could be slightly misleading, but I don't know what else they could be called really. When people ask for an "nth-of-type" selector, the answer is `:eq(n)`, but the equivalent `.eq(n)` method is faster.

Comment: I really like the eq() solution, it's very readable and will be the one I'll be using from here on.  Check out these results though, uses nth-of-type and first-of-type: http://jsperf.com/jq-first-vs-eq/3

Comment: @rkw - Nice! Good discovery. I didn't know you could use `:nth-of-type` and the like with jQuery.

Comment: I didn't either till I tried it.  It's not in the documentation, so maybe jQuery just passes the selector straight through if it doesn't recognize it?  Also, I don't think it's behaving the way I'm expecting it to.  Example: on this page, if you type $('div:first-of-type') in the console, you will get over 70 results.  I was expecting one.

Comment: Ah, first-of-type is designed to be used with a parent. It all makes sense now. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo

Comment: @rkw - Probably worth noting that `:first-of-type` and the like will *only work in browsers that support `querySelectorAll`*. Older browsers (in particular IE8 and below) will throw an error, so probably best to stick with `eq`.

Comment: Thanks guys! - intruiging disgussion. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('div p:first')
```

answer was too short to post without this useless sentence.

**Edit**
This is definitely a slow option.  After looking at Jame's speed test, it looks like jQuery selectors work best when they piggy back off of css selectors.

Comment: @JamesAllardice That's equal to .First(), because both matches one single element. Whether it's the desired effect depends on  Web_Designer's challenge.

Comment: @Farrell - Yes, it's equal to `.first` and `:first` and `:eq(0)` and `:lt(1)` (there are so many ways of writing the same thing with jQuery), but it should be the fasted of the bunch.

Comment: @rkw - Note that `:nth-child` is not equivalent and won't work in this case. You are right in thinking that selectors work best when they have a CSS equivalent, especially in modern browsers, because the native `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` methods can be used instead of Sizzle.

Answer (score 1):

$("div p").first();

or $('div p:first');

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Keep in mind that first() matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent.

Answer (score 1):

You almost know the answer (from your post title). There is a selector in jQuery called `:first-of-type`. Use it to find and add class to the first p tag automatically, like so:

```
$("div p:first-of-type").addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: :first-of-type and :last-of-type is available since jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div p').first()
```

Should work.  I think.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
$( "div p:first-of-type" ).css( "font-size: 10px" );
```

The above code finds the first paragraph in the div as @Denver pointed and changed its `fonts-size`  to `10px`

Here is an example that explains even more about [jQuery first-of-type selector](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-first-of-type-selector)

Comment: No, it shouldn't. This answer is, essentially, identical to [the one given by Devner two and a half years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16381687/19068) except you've changed it to select the wrong element.