# Iterate and add Class to Each Paragraph

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class "ignore" to the first P and a class "style" for the last P for each block.

```
<div class="tiles_large">
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
       <p>image here</p>
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
       <h4>headline here</h4>
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
       <p>content here</p>
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tiles_small">
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
       <p>image here</p>
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
       <h4><div><span>headline here</span></div></h4>
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
       <p>content here</p>
    <span class="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
```

This is my jquery, but it's not returning the expected results.

```
  $(".tiles_large p,.tiles_small p").each(function() {
    $(this).find("p:first").addClass("ignore");
  });

  $(".tiles_large p,.tiles_small p").each(function() {
    $(this).find("p:last").addClass("style");
  });
```

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsg3m/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gsg3m/5/). If so, you don't need to use **.each** function.

```
$(".tiles_large,.tiles_small").find("p:first").addClass("ignore").end().find("p:last").addClass("style");
```

Comment: that's a much cleaner and simplyer way to do that for sure. i thought i had to use the .each function. thanks for the insight

Comment: @Evan you can do it using **.each** and **.find** functions but in this case it is not necessary. One advantage (and at the same time disadvantage) of jQuery is that sometimes you can do one thing by different ways

Comment: i just realized, when i put my code into place, when i have more than just 2 blocks, lets say 8 blocks, then i would need to use the .each

Comment: @Evan You still don't need **.each** function. In fact you only need one expression. See my updated answer and try it in your code. If you told me that it had more than 2 blocks I would answer differently

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks for that! that worked perfectly and again, very clean.

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for the `p` element inside `.tiles_large p` and `.tiles_small p`, whereas it should just be `.tiles_large` and `.tiles_small`.

Updating that results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsg3m/2/)

```
$(".tiles_large,.tiles_small").each(function () {
    $(this).find("p:first").addClass("ignore");
});

$(".tiles_large,.tiles_small").each(function () {
    $(this).find("p:last").addClass("style");
});
```

Comment: man, i so close. That did the trick. i'm such an idiot. thanks for the insight on my error. also, although in my example i provided 2 blocks, but really i have more than just 2 blocks and this iterates through all of them

Answer (score 1):

Use `.titles_large p:first,.titles_small p:first` and remove the complete `.find(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done like this:

```
$(".tiles_large, .tiles_small").each(function() {
    $("p:first", this).addClass("ignore");
    $("p:last", this).addClass("style");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run through `.each`, you are applying the function repeatedly to each `<p>` that gets picked up.  Think you're looking for something more like

```
$(".tiles_large p:first-of-type,.tiles_small p:first-of-type").addClass("ignore");
```

which is basically what @letiagoalves posted.  I guess `first-of-type` is added in jQuery 1.9.  Not sure if there's any specific advantage to it or not...

Edit: found a relevant [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531189/jquery-first-of-type-selector) that talks more about performance of `.find("p").eq(0)` and which browsers may or may not support `first-of-type`. Learned something new myself :)